# ODocument to POJO

Tags: java, orientdb

The original problem is based on loading a class Extra as well as an id with the same query. I want the class Extra to be automatically assigned to a POJO Extra and then handle the id separately. Basically like this:

```
String q = "SELECT *, out('ExtraToObject').@rid as objectId FROM Extra";
List<ODocument> extras= db.getUnderlying().command(new OSQLSynchQuery<>(q)).execute();
for (ODocument extra : extras) {
    Extra extraPOJO = ODocumentToPojo(ODocument, Extra.class);
    String id = extra.field("objectId");

    //Do stuff
}
```

My issue is that I don't know how convert the ODocument to a POJO, that is the ODocumentToPojo function, without doing any database connection.

```
String q = "SELECT *, out('ExtraToObject').@rid as objectId FROM Extra";
List<Extra> extras= db.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<>(q)).execute();
```

But the I wouldn't be able to get the objectId. Neither do I want to loop through the ODocument myself if not absolutely necessary since the mapping between the two should already exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only get `rid` from pojo you can define it as field:

```
@Id
private Object rid;

public Object getRid() {
    return rid;
}
```

If you need conversation, it describes in [documentation](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Object-Database#get-the-pojo-from-a-record):

```
Object pojo = db.getUserObjectByRecord(record);
ODocument doc = db.getRecordByUserObject( pojo );
```